# Restarting child process

Tags: node.js

I have a main process that spawns child processes. When the child process is killed, it is restarted, but when it is killed again, it will not restart.

test.js

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const path = require('path');
const test = path.resolve('test2.js');
let test_child = fork(test);

test_child.on("close", () => {
    console.log("child gone");
    setTimeout(() => {
        test_child = fork(test);
    }, 2500)
});
```

test2.js

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log("test")
}, 250);
```

I want the main process (test.js), to continually start up (test2.js) if it ever crashes or stops for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const path = require('path');
const test = path.resolve('child.js');
function  repeat() {
let test_child = fork(test);

test_child.on("close", () => {
    console.log("child gone");
    setTimeout(() => {
      repeat();
    }, 25)
});
}

repeat();
```

You can try the above code in your main.js

Comment: Can let test_child = fork(test); not be outside the function scope?

Comment: Never mind got it and working. Thanks. Went with this:const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const path = require('path');
const test = path.resolve('test2.js');

let test_child

function repeat() {
    test_child = fork(test);
    test_child.on("close", () => {
        console.log("child gone");
        setTimeout(() => {
            repeat();
        }, 2500)
    });
}

repeat();

Answer (score 0):

If you can check the status of your child process, you can add it to a setInterval function checking if it is running or not, and if not just call it again

Comment: That's what test_child = fork(test); is doing here inside the setTimeout. It works the first time, no problem, but any time after the first, it will just end the main process.

Comment: The problem, is that setTimeout is supposed to run just one time after 25ms, and setInterval will repeat that after 25ms